# Best practice: Typescript: Let a customer extend an application with custom code

Tags: javascript, angular, plugins, runtime

we have an angular 9 based application framework, which gives a customer the possibility to configurate an application with fields and layouts. This works pretty nice.

But now we get to the point, where a customer wants to implement special features, like "He enters a value into a textfield and a request to a 3rd party software should be fired to load new data and autofill other values".

We could implement every possible interaction or allow to create custom snippets in javascript.

But in the past i have had a lot of bad experience with these base javascript snippets because they didn't have the needed standard functionality like typescript provides me.

1) Is there a way how a user can create custom code during runtime with typescript rather than plane javascript?

Yes i know typecript needs to be compiled before running, but I ask because I want to know if there is another way?

2) Alternative question:
Can a user develop an angular application and add it as plugin during runtime? Something like an extension or a custom functionality which will be added to the portal for the customer which is not part of the base framework?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question well but from my point of view the only way that an other user want to interact with the main Angular project is that `he create a library` by using the command `ng generate library my-lib`. (https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

From there he can create a new module and then someone else import this new lib into the main project and that's it.

The new lib can be maintained by the "customer" and he can release new version of it if the lib is hosted in npm repository and from the main application just need to `npm i customer-lib@latest`

Did I answerd to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is we have a hosted cloud application, where we have a standard implementation which is already compiled and deployed in a docker container.

Now a customer should have the possibility to extend the functionality by adding scripts and modules. Like it is common for example in wordpress. Where you have a standard implementation and if you want another wysiwyg Editor you install a plugin.

I know the only way of injecting code is via javascript but I just wanted to ask if there is another solution for this which will not lead to redploy the whole application.